# Java Swing app looks ugly in Windows 7

Tags: java, swing, windows-7, look-and-feel

I'm trying to make the Swing widgets (JButtons, JComboBoxes, JButtons) in my app look like they do in Windows 7.
Starting off, they look like this:

[image: Imgur]

Ugh, gross. So everyone claims this code will make my widgets look like Windows 7 widgets:

```
 UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Here's how that looks:

[image: IMgur]

Slightly better (the buttons are improved), not but great. Looks like an old-style Windows application.
What I want is something like this (from Audacity):

[image: Imgur]

Any ideas? Java 7 on Windows 7.

**Edit:**

Tried this:

```
package test;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Test {

Test() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hello!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
}

}
```

Which gives me this:

[image: Imgur]

So the problem is elsewhere. Good to know above should always work. Thanks.

**Edit 2:**

The problem was I was using **-Dswing.noxp=true**.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your current approach.

Comment: What does `System.out.println(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` print? It should be `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel`